# Query database from reader loop

Tags: .net, npgsql

I have problem to query database from reader's loop:

```
    Using cn As NpgsqlConnection = getConnection()
        Using t As NpgsqlTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction()
           Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT tab_id, i1, d1, rez1, b FROM " & myfirstTable & " WHERE bdoc='" & bdoc.ToString & "' ORDER BY b", cn)
                Using reader1 As NpgsqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    --------------> ''GOES HERE
    |               While (reader1.Read())
    |                   Dim sifra As Integer = CInt(reader1("sifra"))
    | 
    |                       Using icmd As New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT dtbl_id FROM " & mysecondTable & " WHERE dtbl_id>" & firstfree.ToString & " AND kni::int=0 ORDER BY dtbl_id LIMIT 1", cn)
    |               
    --------------------------- ''FROM HERE
                                firstfree = CInt(icmd.ExecuteScalar())
                            End Using ''cmd

                    End While
                End Using ''reader
            End Using ''cmd
            t.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using
```

While reader's.read loop I have to get integer firstfree from new query to database.
My command work's good by testing in pgAdmin.
But in showed program don't.
When firstfree = CInt(icmd.ExecuteScalar()) is going to be executed ''FROM HERE program jumps to new loop step ''GOES HERE

Is something obvious incorrect here and how to get that working?

Here is getConnection function.

```
Public Function getConnection() As NpgsqlConnection

    Dim chkCon As New NpgsqlConnection(String.Format( _
                      "Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};Preload Reader = true;", _
                      dbServer, dbPort, dbUser, dbPass, mydatabase))
    Try
        chkCon.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Return chkCon
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what your language is, etc. but it does seem to me you have two obvious typos in your loops.

For example, should:

```
 End Using ''cmd
```

be

```
 End Using ''icmd
```

and should

```
 End Using ''reader
```

be

```
 End Using ''reader1
```

At any rate this looks like a loop syntax issue, so I would look at debugging as a .net issue rather than a PostgreSQL issue.

Comment: No, this is obviously visual basic where ' mean a comment and  everything after first ' is a comment. I use two '' because SO can handle this better, similar to C style comments //. Here was syntax issue with PostgreSQL where bdoc is integer and shouldn't be closed with single quotes like string.